# Executing multiple command shell from java

Tags: java

I was looking for a manner to execute several commans shell from java. I found this in stackoverflow but it helps only for executing one command shell per session :

```
try {  
        // Execute command  
        String command = "ls -la";  
        StringBuffer ret=new StringBuffer();  
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  

        // Get the input stream and read from it  
        InputStream in = child.getInputStream();  
        int c;  
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {  
        ret.append((char)c);  
        }  
        in.close();  
        System.out.println(ret.toString());  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

is there anyway to execute many commands in the same session using code above ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write this code inside a `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could group the commands in a shell script, and execute just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an executable shell script or bat file with a bunch of commands and execute it as one command.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that's not how you use [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29): The first parameter is the *executable*, the others are the parameters to that executable.

Right now, your code is trying to execute a file called literally `"ls -la"`, which of course doesn't exist.

Change your code to this:

```
String[] command = {"ls", "-la"}; // Use an array
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, is there anyway to do it with several commands shell calls?